# layout issues when IE9 Compatability View is Off

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I am having trouble in my layout in IE9 compatibility View `On` . In all major browsers (including IE9 compatibility view off), the layout is fine. But it seems like textarea stays shrunk in IE9 and text inputs are shrunk. Below show the difference between the wanted layout in the other browsers and the incorrect layout in the IE9 compatibility view:

[image]

My question is simply how to fix the layout?

I have provided a jsfiddle to show the code: http://jsfiddle.net/U9Nm8/embedded/result/
(IN JSFiddle the layout looks fine)

Answer (score 1):

Just add HTTP-response header or meta element `X-UA-Compatible` with `IE=edge` value to prevent user from switching to compatibility view mode:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Compatibility view mode is not intended to develop websites for, and you should not care about how your standards-compliant site looks in IE with this mode turned on. Compatibility view mode just helps to view old outdated sites developed for old IE versions and that otherwise work incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah but I need it working in compatibility view because in the university computers, they have been set as default in compatibility view is on and it can't be turned off. So I need it working in compatibility view. Any Ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, `X-UA-Compatible` with `IE=edge` value disables Compatibility view mode anyway. Have you tried to add `X-UA-Compatible` as I've described? In general, AFAIK, in compatibility view mode, IE8+ operates as IE 5.5, so, to make your page working in compatibility view mode, you should make the page working in IE 5.5. ;-)

Comment: Ohhhhhh, so if it disable compatibility view then it has no choice but to go for the normal IE9 view? At moment though my meta is `  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
` do I need to replace it completely or can I add the others to it? I don't really understand what my meta does, I have just always included it

Comment: There can be any number of meta elements. `http-equiv` ones are equivalents to server's HTTP-response headers of same name. For example, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` is equivalent to `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` server response header. You should add this meta element without removing any other meta elements (`Content-Type` meta-element in particular has nothing to do with `X-UA-Compatible` one).

Comment: For general information on `meta` HTML-element, see [W3C wiki page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/meta), [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META), and [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element).